# Как вернуться два фрагмента назад

Tags: android

при нажатии на кнопку перехожу с начального фрагмента на фрагмент добавления пункта и сохраняю . при нажатии на кнопку назад я не перехожу на начальный фрагмент а перехожу в фрагмент добавления где осталось то што я добавил а подом переходет на начальный фрагмент.

как после сохранения при нажатии на кнопку назад перейти на начальный фрагмент ?

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragmnet_container,  EditStudie , "A");
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Ловите нажатие кнопки назад и делайте

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: получилось я убрал с фрагмента добления    transaction.addToBackStack(null);